# conversion of numeric string into md5 with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery plug in for converting the string into md5.following is the link of jquery md5 plug in.
"http://code.google.com/p/openfire-websockets/source/browse/trunk/plugin/ofchat/js/background/jquery.md5.js?r=7"
But the problem is, I can convert only string into md5 by this.but when I am using numeric value such as time stamp.it produces error.
is there any other method or plug in by which I can convert numeric value in md5 by jquery.

Comment: You could convert your numeric value to string first.

Comment: As @lanzz said, simply convert it to String, probably the easiest way to do it is to pass `(""+numericValue)` to the plugin

Comment: `""+numericValue` is a horrible unreadable kludge. I'd use `numericValue.toString()` or `String(numericValue)`.

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5